# Change column size to fit text

Tags: tables, tabularx, width

Can someone help me? I am trying to wrap the text in each column so the last column has the largest width.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{makecell, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\footnotesize
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}           {|*{6}{ L| } } 
    \hline
    \thead[b]{Risk}  
    &   \thead[b]{Likelihood}                        
    &   \thead[b]{Impact}                        
    &   \thead[b]{Overall}
    &   \thead[b]{Response}                                               
    \\ \hline
    Going over budget      
    &   M                          
    &   L
    &   M
    &   \textbf{Preventative:} Keep track of all spending and have clearance of all potential spending by all project team members as well as the sponsor.
    \\ \hline
    Not having staff ambassadors
    &   M    
    &   L                           
    &   M
    &   \textbf{Preventative:} Ask as many staff members as possible to maximise the chances of having staff agreeing to represent their school. 
    \\ \hline
    Small turnout for event                
    &   M                         
    &   M
    &   M
    &   \textbf{Preventative:} Raise awareness for the event for at least a month in advance and continue to raise awareness.\newline \textbf{Opportunity:} Allows for a more intimate event and gain detailed attendee feedback                                                    
    \\ \hline
    Not meeting project event deadline                
    &    L
    &    H
    &    M
    &   \textbf{Preventive:} Ensure that all project team members meet their individual task deadlines and allow for some float time by constructing a critical path analysis
    \\ \hline
    Reaching venue capacity               
    &    M
    &    H
    &    M
    &   \textbf{Preventive:} Have attendees RSVP to the event to give an indication of numbers for the event which will allow the project team \newline 
    \textbf{Opportunity:} Allows for a bigger audience for the team to deliver the presentation to and create greater awareness of the collaboration tool.
    \\ \hline
    Technical issues during showcase              
    &    H
    &    H
    &    H
    &   \textbf{Preventive:} test all technical equipment before event begins\newline
    \textbf{Corrective:} have back-up devices ready \newline
    Connect to mobile phone internet 
    \\ \hline
    Catering for event does not deliver              
    &    M
    &    L
    &    M
    &   \textbf{Preventive:} Confirm with catering providers that food and drink will be delivered on time\newline 
    \textbf{Corrective:  }
    \\ \hline
    Sponsor does not agree with event plans             
    &    L
    &    H
    &    M
    &   \textbf{Preventive:} have continuous communication with the sponsor and have them sign everything off
    \\ \hline   
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Where do you get `\thead` and the column type `L` from? Please provide all the necessary information so we can copy-and-paste-and-compile your code... not just a code snippet.

Comment: @Werner sorry, just added it now

Comment: It's unfortunate that you didn't read my comment suggesting you provide *all* the necessary information. What `\documentclass` are you using? Where does `cmptable` come from? I know it may not be necessary for this question, but it'll make your problem easily reproducable.

Comment: Hi @Werner I was provided with a cmp cls file which has over 1000 lines. I did not want to spam this forum and thought it would be best to just have a snippet. All I need to know is how to change the column width so that the last column is the biggest.

Comment: @Werner: `\thead` is defined by `makecell`.

Comment: By asking for the `\documentclass`, I'm not asking you to post 1000 lines from some `.cls`. But you can at least provide the name. All we need to know are the details... I'll fix up your code to show you what you should provide...

Comment: @werner    \documentclass[final]{nbsreport}

Comment: Why are the columns two to four are not using column type `l`, `c`, or `r`?

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek I have tried. I am not sure and just want to make sure the text wraps so that they all are the min size they need.

Answer (score 2):

The following uses a fixed-width column for the first column - `p{<len>}`, followed by three `c`entred columns and a final `X`-like column (that uses a `\raggedright` alignment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{makecell, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\begingroup
\footnotesize
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}%
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{ | >{\raggedright}p{5em} | *{3}{ c| } L| } 
    \hline
    \thead[b]{Risk}  
    &   \thead[b]{Likelihood}                        
    &   \thead[b]{Impact}                        
    &   \thead[b]{Overall}
    &   \thead[b]{Response}                                               
    \\ \hline
    Going over budget      
    &   M                          
    &   L
    &   M
    &   \textbf{Preventative:} Keep track of all spending and have clearance of all potential spending by all project team members as well as the sponsor.
    \\ \hline
    Not having staff ambassadors
    &   M    
    &   L                           
    &   M
    &   \textbf{Preventative:} Ask as many staff members as possible to maximise the chances of having staff agreeing to represent their school. 
    \\ \hline
    Small turnout for event                
    &   M                         
    &   M
    &   M
    &   \textbf{Preventative:} Raise awareness for the event for at least a month in advance and continue to raise awareness.\newline \textbf{Opportunity:} Allows for a more intimate event and gain detailed attendee feedback                                                    
    \\ \hline
    Not meeting project event deadline                
    &    L
    &    H
    &    M
    &   \textbf{Preventive:} Ensure that all project team members meet their individual task deadlines and allow for some float time by constructing a critical path analysis
    \\ \hline
    Reaching venue capacity               
    &    M
    &    H
    &    M
    &   \textbf{Preventive:} Have attendees RSVP to the event to give an indication of numbers for the event which will allow the project team \newline 
    \textbf{Opportunity:} Allows for a bigger audience for the team to deliver the presentation to and create greater awareness of the collaboration tool.
    \\ \hline
    Technical issues during showcase              
    &    H
    &    H
    &    H
    &   \textbf{Preventive:} test all technical equipment before event begins\newline
    \textbf{Corrective:} have back-up devices ready \newline
    Connect to mobile phone internet 
    \\ \hline
    Catering for event does not deliver              
    &    M
    &    L
    &    M
    &   \textbf{Preventive:} Confirm with catering providers that food and drink will be delivered on time\newline 
    \textbf{Corrective:  }
    \\ \hline
    Sponsor does not agree with event plans             
    &    L
    &    H
    &    M
    &   \textbf{Preventive:} have continuous communication with the sponsor and have them sign everything off
    \\ \hline   
\end{tabularx}
\endgroup

\end{document}
```

You can fiddle with the length `<len>` to suit your needs.

Note that your table only has five columns (you've set `*{6}{..}`). Also, I've used a `%` after `\setlength{\tabcolsep}{3pt}` as it introduces a [spurious space that you want to avoid](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/7453/5764).

Answer (score 2):

Or alternatively resize `L` column type:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{makecell, tabularx}
\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage{rotating}

\usepackage{geometry}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
\caption{Risk Register \label{table6}}
\footnotesize
\setlength\tabcolsep{3pt}
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{|>{\hsize=0.5\hsize}L|*{3}{ c| } >{\hsize=1.5\hsize}L | }
    \hline
    \thead{Risk}
    &   \thead{Likelihood}
    &   \thead{Impact}
    &   \thead{Overall}
    &   \thead{Response}
    \\ \hline
    Going over budget
    &   M
    &   L
    &   M
    &   \textbf{Preventative:} Keep track of all spending and have clearance of all potential spending by all project team members as well as the sponsor.
    \\ \hline
    Not having staff ambassadors
    &   M
    &   L
    &   M
    &   \textbf{Preventative:} Ask as many staff members as possible to maximise the chances of having staff agreeing to represent their school.
    \\ \hline
    Small turnout for event
    &   M
    &   M
    &   M
    &   \textbf{Preventative:} Raise awareness for the event for at least a month in advance and continue to raise awareness.\newline \textbf{Opportunity:} Allows for a more intimate event and gain detailed attendee feedback
    \\ \hline
    Not meeting project event deadline
    &    L
    &    H
    &    M
    &   \textbf{Preventive:} Ensure that all project team members meet their individual task deadlines and allow for some float time by constructing a critical path analysis
    \\ \hline
    Reaching venue capacity
    &    M
    &    H
    &    M
    &   \textbf{Preventive:} Have attendees RSVP to the event to give an indication of numbers for the event which will allow the project team \newline
    \textbf{Opportunity:} Allows for a bigger audience for the team to deliver the presentation to and create greater awareness of the collaboration tool.
    \\ \hline
    Technical issues during showcase
    &    H
    &    H
    &    H
    &   \textbf{Preventive:} test all technical equipment before event begins\newline
    \textbf{Corrective:} have back-up devices ready \newline
    Connect to mobile phone internet
    \\ \hline
    Catering for event does not deliver
    &    M
    &    L
    &    M
    &   \textbf{Preventive:} Confirm with catering providers that food and drink will be delivered on time\newline
    \textbf{Corrective:  }
    \\ \hline
    Sponsor does not agree with event plans
    &    L
    &    H
    &    M
    &   \textbf{Preventive:} have continuous communication with the sponsor and have them sign everything off
    \\ \hline
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]